# SQL REPLACE statement not returning expected results with subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

This question is in regards to SQL Server 2005. I have 2 UDFs, 1 that does a look up on a country codes table that contains 2 columns; "code" which contains a country's abbreviation and "name" which contains the country's name. Both of these UDF's get passed an address and does a look up based on the string being broken up with a UDF that splits the string.

For example:

```
SELECT dbo.GetCountryName('SAMPALOC MANILA PHILIPPINES 1000')
```

returns "PHILIPPINES" and

```
SELECT dbo.GetCountryCode('SAMPALOC MANILA PHILIPPINES 1000')
```

returns "PH."

These are working perfectly but when I use them in a REPLACE  statement:

```
SELECT REPLACE(('SAMPALOC MANILA PHILIPPINES 1000'),
(SELECT dbo.GetCountryName('SAMPALOC MANILA PHILIPPINES 1000')),  
(SELECT dbo.GetCountryCode('SAMPALOC MANILA PHILIPPINES 1000')))
```

I get "SAMPALOC MANILA PHILIPPINES 1000" and what I need it be is "SAMPALOC MANILA PH 1000." I need do this in cases where the address as a whole has a length > 60.

I have no idea why putting this in a REPLACE statement is causing this to fail. Has anyone else run into this or have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Sure the `GetCountryName` UDF doesn't return a value with trailing spaces? Possibly `char` datatype instead of `varchar`?

Comment: Yes, @Martin is right.If functions are returning the values what you have mentioned then replace function is working as required.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it was. The UDF's were returning trailing spaces. The replace function is working correctly now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encased my return variable in the UDF in LTRIM and RTRIM functions. Problem solved.